# Laravel 5 sends email only to the first address in array

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5, swiftmailer

Here's the code I'm using to send an e-mail to multiple recipients:

```php
$recipients = ['myoneemail@esomething.com', 'myother@esomething.com','myother2@esomething.com'];

Mail::send(['admin.emails.email.html', 'admin.emails.email.text'], ['content' => $request->input('message')],
function ($message) use ($request, $recipients) {
    $message
            ->to($recipients)
            ->subject($request->input('subject'))
            ->replyTo('xxx@xxx.com', 'Me');
});
```

I'm using Mailtrap.io as a fake inbox to catch the e-mails. I only get the mail sent to "myoneemail@esomething.com", not the other ones.

But why ?

Comment: I don't know how Mailtrap.io works, so the answers to my question might not be too helpful but... Are you using one inbox as a catch-all, or do you have one inbox for each address?

Comment: I have only one inbox in Mailtrap, supposed to catch everything.

Comment: I wouldn't think that Mailtrap would reject emails with a velocity filter, but what happens if you add a "real" email address to the array?

Comment: Well, even if the addresses I provided in the example doesn't really exist, I do believe they are "real". Anyways I already tried with existing addresses and I had the same result.

Comment: I'm out of ideas unless you want to start adding debug code into the Laravel classes to see what it's doing with your array.